# Navigation Lint Error: This navigation graph is not referenced from any layout files

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-editor

I have 2 modules in my app (app module and splash module). I'm trying to leverage the `<include>` tag in an effort to make the [FTUE](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#first-time_user_experience) self contained and not a part of the main nav graph as the docs suggest.

My main nav graph is defined in the app module and looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/home">

  <include app:graph="@navigation/splash_nav_graph"/>

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/home"
      android:name="com.example.Home"
      android:label="fragment_home"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_home_to_splash_nav_graph"
        app:destination="@id/splash_nav_graph"/>
  </fragment>

</navigation>
```

`splash_nav_graph` is defined in the splash module (app module obviously has a dependency on it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/splash_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
      android:name="com.example.splash.SplashFragment"
      android:label="example"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_signInFragment"
        app:destination="@id/signInFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
  </fragment>

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/signInFragment"
      android:name="com.example.splash.signin.ui.SignInFragment"
      android:label="fragment_sign_in"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sign_in">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_signInFragment_pop"
        app:popUpTo="@id/splash_nav_graph"/>
  </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Finally, here's the layout where the *main* nav graph is tied to the NavHostFragment back in the app module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
      android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:defaultNavHost="true"
      app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
      />

</LinearLayout>
```

This will run and navigating through the flow (home-> splash -> sign in -> home) yields the expected behavior. However, the following lint error is present at the top of `splash_nav_graph`:

`This navigation graph is not referenced from any layout files (expected to find it in at least one layout file with a NavHostFragment with app:navGraph="@navigation/splash_nav_graph" attribute). more... (⌘F1)`

What the lint error says *is* true (I don't have another `NavHostFragment` that has `app:navGraph="@navigation/splash_nav_graph"`) , however:

- I am including it into another graph and it's working (thinking there is that this is somehow transitive and lint can't detect that)
- I have no idea where to add another `NavHostFragment` because I only have a single activity in the app module.

Do I actually need to add another `NavHostFragment` somewhere or is this a bug in lint?

Comment: Sounds like a false positive from Lint that you should [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=404706) to fix.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to this so quickly. Saved me a ton of time and lots of hair!

Comment: Created issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134078644) for those interested in following it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this will be fixed in [AS 3.6](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134078644)

Comment: I use Android Studio 4.0. Beta 5 and its still not fixed.

Comment: I use Android Studio 4.0.1 and its still not fixed.